# How to say noun with/without noun

Tags: grammar, usage, particles

How do I express the concept of with/without in the following sentences:

> I'd like a coffee with sugar please.

The best I can do is to use 'and':

> コーヒーとさとうを下さい

And for 'without':

> I'd like a pizza without cheese.

My best attempt at this would be:

> チーズがないピザを下さい

Maybe I could re-engineer the coffee and sugar one in that way too. It seems clunky though. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pizza without cheese :

> チーズ無しピザを下さい

Shoyu Ramen without garlic

> 醤油ラーメンニンニク抜き

With cheese

> チーズ付き

Curry with Tomato

> トマト入りカレーを下さい

You don't ask for sugar in your coffee since you have to pour it yourself in most coffee shop.

Answer (score 5):

抜き is also an option for 'without':

> チーズ抜きピザ

Answer (score 1):

ピザはチーズ抜きお願いします。
piza wa chiizu nuki onegaishimasu.

You can also use なし:
ピザはチーズなしお願いします。

When I want to drink water without ice. I just say the following:
水は氷なしお願いします。

mizu wa kouri nashi onegaishimasu